# Arabic Characters Display as ??? in Power BI connected with Oracle 12c over ODBC

Tags: oracle, powerbi, oracle12c

I am trying to connect power Bi with Oracle DB 12c via ODBC, but the arabic characters displays as (??? question marks). I have checked the database in sql developer and it was displayed fine.

[image]

I have changed the CHARACTER SET to AR8ISO8859P6 just in case

```
SQL> SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' ;

VALUE$
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AR8ISO8859P6
```

and the sdl_lang on registry  to AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256

[image]

[image]

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;

PARAMETER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION
12.2.0.1.0

NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP
FALSE

NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS
BYTE


PARAMETER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_COMP
BINARY

NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY
$

NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT
DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR


PARAMETER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT
HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR

NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT
DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM

NLS_TIME_FORMAT
HH.MI.SSXFF AM


PARAMETER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_SORT
BINARY

NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE
AMERICAN

NLS_DATE_FORMAT
DD-MON-RR


PARAMETER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_CALENDAR
GREGORIAN

NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS
.,

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET
AL16UTF16


PARAMETER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET
AR8ISO8859P6

NLS_ISO_CURRENCY
AMERICA

NLS_CURRENCY
$


PARAMETER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_TERRITORY
AMERICA

NLS_LANGUAGE
AMERICAN


20 rows selected.
```

and the sql developer is fine the arabic is display correct

but when I connect power bi with oracle db it displays the arabic as ????

[image]

how can I fix this issue?

---

*UPDATE: Change Windows Region To Arabic:*

I have changed windows to Arabic Even on power Bi region setting still not Arabic not displayed correct

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @miracle173  The data I have is a backup from old database, i imported and try to connect again, the database characterset  is `AR8ISO8859P6`, I have updated the question

Comment: @AhmadSaleh in the powerbuilder ini, add characterset = utf8, also make sure in controle panel regeional setting arabic is added

Comment: @Moudiz how to access powerbuilder ini file ?

Comment: @AhmadSaleh how you are connecting to the database ? is there a parameter file for that ?

Comment: @Moudiz I am connecting using ODBC

Comment: @AhmadSaleh then check please control panel regional .. region .. admistrative.. change system locate to arabic .. give a try i work with sybase applications

Comment: It seems that you have imported your data. Is this true? Which kind of import, datapump (impdp) or the old export tool (exp)? What was the character set of original database?

Comment: could you dump the fisrt b_name tha you display, e.g. `select dump(b_name) from builds where t_no=1 and g_no=0 and b_no=32 and flr_count=6 and city_no=1 and part_no=4`

Comment: @Moudiz I have updated the post, changing the region on windows and power bi but yet arabic not displayed correctly

Comment: @miracle173 I have changed the NLS_LANG to AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8ISO8859P6 , and restart the system, yet Arabic are displayed as ?????

Comment: @miracle173  the result of dump first b-name is -> Typ=1 Len=10: 199,228,217,210,234,210,234,201,32,50

Comment: Do you use an Oracle ODBC driver or do you use a Microsoft ODBC driver for your connection?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I saw two alternatives:

1. Replace ODBC to a Oracle Driver connection (best solution, because it resolves automatic updates issues in a report server)
2. Set enviroment variable NLS_LANG in your SO to the same DB parameter value.